# Comma before "which"

Tags: punctuation

I am editing a court transcript for a class (cannot alter the text). For each change I make, I need to cite a rule for it. I have read a lot about the use of *which* and *that*, and I am still confused on this sentence.

I feel that it needs a comma before *which*, but I am unsure what the “official” reasoning would be. I know that, normally, *that* should be used for restrictive clauses, and *which* should be used for non-restrictive clauses, but I am unsure if it was spoken correctly.

Or is it because there is only one Exhibit 2, making the *which* clause non-essential (non-restrictive), and therefore a comma is needed?

> We’ve put in front of you Exhibit 2 which is a Visa statement of account.

Comment: Please do not put commas inside your quote marks when you are talking about things where it actually matters: there needs to be a difference between **"which"**, **"which,"**, **"that"**, and **"that,"**, or no one will understand what you mean.  I’ve switched your formatting to the preferred italic version instead of using quotes to help make this clearer.

Comment: Yes/No answers are GR; the rest are 'mainly opinion-based' OTs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your example, *which is a Visa statement of account* looks like a supplementary (non-restrictive, non-defining) relative clause, although it would be necessary to see the wider context to be sure. If it is, then a comma before *which* would be appropriate for that reason.

For more on *which* and *that*, [see here](http://chronicle.com/blogs/linguafranca/2012/12/07/a-rule-which-will-live-in-infamy/).

Comment: Sorry, everyone- I should have researched how things work here before I started posting! I've now figured out how to accept answers. I apologize for my ignorance; no ill-will intended!

Comment: @jennifer That's but natural, relax. You may delete that comment even, it's not needed.

Comment: *Follow the Fowler rule if you want to; it’s up to you,* is what Pullum concluded there. Not much help.

Answer (score 2):

For many English writers (nobody knows how many, but at least a substantial minority -- or maybe a majority -- of the best ones), comma usage is **not** a matter of grammar, so which word is used is irrelevant -- rather, it's the intonation of the **spoken** words that counts.

These English writers use commas to [indicate intonation dips](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/commas.html). And many English readers interpret them that way. Certainly I do.

So the rule is to **listen** to the transcript of the speakers' **voices**, and put in commas according to their intonation.

Failing that, **any** insertion of commas into a text-only legal transcript **is** altering the document, since it offers the judgements of the editor instead of the transcriber.

Comment: Once in a while, that comma has a great semantic significance. And considering the OP's context of legal drafting, that can mean a lot. Well said, *any insertion of commas into a text-only legal transcript is altering the document*, in its spirit though not letter.

Comment: Once in a while, that intonation dip has a great semantic significance. If you can hear it in your mind's ear.

Answer (score -1):

You need a comma in that situation. "Which" is used for non-restrictive clauses, that for restrictive clauses.

Comment: Not true. See here: http://chronicle.com/blogs/linguafranca/2012/12/07/a-rule-which-will-live-in-infamy/

Comment: @BarrieEngland  It is distressing how many of these “invented” non(sense)-rules are used to bash people with. I wanted a nice canonical rebuttal, and had once read something like this that Pullum published previously, but had misplaced it.  So thanks for the new link.

Comment: @aszekely - Except that in reality, it isn't actually true that "which" is used exclusively for non-restrictive clauses and "that" for restrictive. This is an invention that *some* commentators advocate but there is no intrinsic compulsion to follow it and it is far from universally adopted. Or in other words, you only "need" a comma *if* you arbitrarily decide to follow that convention.